# Is there a vectorized implementation of this cost function?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, vectorization

I'm going through Andrew Ng's course on machine learning and am currently writing a forward propagation code in MATLAB/Octave that solves this cost function:

[image]

Currently, I have wrote it in a for loop form like this:

```
for i= 1:m
  for j= 1:num_labels
    J = J + log(ht(j,i))*y(j,i) + log(1-ht(j,i))*(1-y(j,i));
  end
end

J = -J/m;
```

And that gets the job done. However, I would like to simplify this code, as I always feel a little "dirty" using for loops in MATLAB when I feel I could be using a vectorized form. But the for loops seem natural since there are 2 summations.

Comment: `j = -sum(sum(log(ht).*y+log(1-ht).*y))/m;`

Comment: that's not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should give you the same result as your loop code above:

```
J = -sum(log(ht(:)).*y(:) + log(1-ht(:)).*(1-y(:)))/m;
```

The [colon operator `(:)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) is used to reshape each matrix into a column vector so that after element-wise multiplication a single call to [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) can be used to add up all the results.

Comment: Nice! Just curious, is this kind of implementation faster than the nested for loop method?

Comment: @DavisOwen: It probably depends somewhat on how large `m` and `num_labels` are. Loops in current versions of MATLAB aren't as terrible as they once were, so for a simple enough operation as this there might not be a huge difference in speed. My gut says you'd probably see a moderate improvement from vectorization. When in doubt, you can just [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html)!